# Is reference dot pattern of Asus Xtion Pro Live same as Kinect

Tags: computer-vision, kinect, asus-xtion, primesense

I know that both *Microsoft Kinect* and *Asus Xtion Pro Live* use PrimeSense technology to estimate depth, as described here:

http://lttm.dei.unipd.it/nuovo/Papers/ToF-Kinect-book.pdf

However, I was wondering: Are the **reference dot patterns** that these devices are using identical, or at least do the same **symmetry** and **pattern repetition rules** apply?

There is some information around about Kinect together with the unveiled reference pattern (not the case for Asus Xtion), so answering this question would be pretty helpful for my understanding while working with Xtion.